# How do I specifically get a static Web image url and apply it to an iPhone application blank view?

Tags: iphone, image

In building an iphone app, I can render a blank view, (say that's all I have, just a generic, full screen view) and I want to populate in that view an image from the web, say, "http://www.mypicture.com/mypicture.jpeg".  I want to do this as fast as the network allows and not use the photo roll or any part of the os that the user can see.  How would I implement this?  Also, how do I capture an snapshot (fullscreen or not) image from Google street view without the user knowing so?  Thanks all for your anticipated time...xobmo

Answer (score 1):

[Use this example](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview), replacing the html with an `<img>` tag with your image as the `src` attribute.

Alternately, you can base64-encode your image [as in this example](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-images-in-uiwebview), but I figure you'll probably do what's easiest.